# Catch Exception and rethrow with a new message preserving actual type

Tags: c#, exception

I have to `catch (Exception ex)`, change its message, and then rethrow it.

If I `throw new Exception(newMessage, ex);`, then I lose the runtime type of the exception, right?

If I `throw;`, then I can keep the runtime type but the message doesn't change.

Since I'm catching, I don't know what derived type `ex` may be, so I can't construct the proper type.

And of course, if I `throw ex;` I lose the stack trace.

Is there a way to reformat the message of `ex` and rethrow it without losing stack or runtime type information, without resorting to any weird brittle reflection hacks?

Comment: throw another type (application type maybe?) and set the original exception as the inner exception

Comment: Why exactly can't you just use the innermost exception of `InnerException`? Do you have a typed `catch` somewhere "above"?

Comment: You have to use custom exception class which derives from base 'Exception' class. This way you can also track in which layer the original exception occurred in a  multi-layer architecture and will be able to log all the exceptions in one place.

Comment: By default, the `Message` property of an exception is read-only.  So unless you are explicitly coding for a specific exception type, you can't just change an exception's message anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have effectively eliminated all reasonable solutions to the problem, the only answer that remains is "no, you can't do this". The `Message` of an `Exception` is read-only. It cannot even be set using "brittle reflection hacks", since the property is `virtual` and therefore not required to come from a backing field at all, for any particular exception type. The following class should demonstrate the impossibility of your demand:

```
sealed class OzymandiasException : Exception {
    public override string Message => "Look upon my message, ye mighty, and despair.";
}
```

There is no way to produce any instance of `OzymandiasException` when caught that will have a different `Message`.